# What is the meaning of 「...みけんならみけん...」?

Tags: grammar

I'm reading a book on how to draw manga style characters, and I came across this sentence. It is part of a larger block explaining how to make a character look the same from all different angles.

> 同{おな}じ髪型{かみがた}といっても、どこから分けてあるか、どんな感{かん}じのカーブで、みけんならみけんのどこまでかかるのか、などに注意{ちゅうい}をはらって描{か}きます

I think I understand the general meaning of the whole sentence, but the part where it says `みけんならみけん` puzzles me a bit. I get that it's talking about where to draw the brow of the face and how far across it goes (`「どこまでかかるのか」`).

As I understand it, なら is something like "being the case that", so I translate `みけんならみけん` as "the brow *as the* brow", but that seems weird to me. How would the brow act as anything other than the brow when drawing a face? My translation must be wrong because it would be redundant to talk about the brow as the brow.

What is `なら` doing in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Even if it's the same hairdo, you draw keeping close attention on where to part it from, what sort of feeling of the curves, and [for/in the case of] the area between the eyebrows how far across to go of that area, etc."

> みけんなら
>   =[for/in the case of] the area between the eyebrows
>
> みけんのどこまでかかるのか
>   =how far across to go of the area between the eyebrows

Comment: Wait... みけん is "eyebrows"? I thought eyebrows was まゆげ.

Comment: @DaveMG oops...`眉間` apparently refers to the area between the eyebrows sorry

Comment: Thanks for confirming the definition. As for the grammar, I think I see it now. There's a conceptual split following なら, so it's not 「けんならみけん...」 as I was reading it before, it's 「みけんなら、みけんのどこまで」...

Comment: @cypher the last "it" in your sentence should refer to the hair(do), not the area between the eyebrows. I.e. "how far the hair goes across the area between the eyebrows".