# Want to be sure I understand the nuance of 払{はら}う

Tags: definitions

`払{はら}う` has a number of meanings, but to summarize, it means to chase away or brush off. I often see it used in combinations like `追{お}い[払]{はら}う`, "to chase off", or "to drive away".

I recently came across the term `はらって描{か}きます` in a book about drawing. The whole sentence I saw it in can be read [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4365/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E3%80%8C-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%91%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%BF%E3%81%91%E3%82%93-%E3%80%8D).

I assume this `はらう` is `払う` and not `祓う`, "to exorcise, to purify". But what exactly does it mean? I'm pretty sure it isn't "to chase away and draw".

I think it might mean "to draw out", in the sense of "to flesh out" - to fill the drawing out by progressively adding detail and adjusting lines to achieve a finished picture.

But I'm not totally confident in that because the dictionary doesn't include any definitions that support a "to fill out" or "to flesh out" definition.

So to confirm whether my guess is right or not, I'd simply like to ask, what *exactly* does `はらって描{か}きます` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your [original question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4365/what-is-the-meaning-of-%E3%80%8C-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%91%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%BF%E3%81%91%E3%82%93-%E3%80%8D):

> …などに注意{ちゅうい}をはらって描{か}きます。

I'm pretty sure it was referring to [`～に注意を[払]{はら}う`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%AB%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F%E3%82%92%E6%89%95%E3%81%86/UTF-8/) "pay attention to" rather than `払って[描]{か}きます`.

I think I could try to write more about `払{はら}う`, but that the [Yahoo JE dictionary](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E6%89%95%E3%81%86&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=03525400) probably already does a better job of explaining than I would be able to.

Comment: So it is important to provide enough context.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I was saying the @DaveMG should including more context in the question. I was about to comment on the question, but got some interruption ...